# Automatic copying data depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet (PLOTS sheet) which contains around 150 different pairs of columns ranging from 10 to 112 rows long. column 1 contains objects, column 2 distances.
On a seperate sheet (Travel sheet) I have a formula which indicates which of these column pairs I need to copy and paste into a specific location in the Travel sheet.
Is there an automatic way of doing this?
Please assume minimal knowledge.

Data in Distance sheet is like below

1 (Number of paired column)
Signal112        123
BridgeD12        135
Signal114        212
Repeater116      240  (but longer, with each paired columns being different lengths)

This data has to be put next to some columns in the Travel sheet which show distance travelled and actions taken by a driver so that the location of the actions taken can be seen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Could you please provide sample data and the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I numbered the pairs of columns so that i could then make a VLOOKUP table with columns 2 and 3 being the columns the data needed was in. Sample below:(4 and 8 have no data available)

1   N        O

2   K   L

3   H   I

4

5   Q   R

6   W   X

7   T   U

8

9   AC  AD

10  Z   AA

So if the formula worked out I needed table 10 in A216 =VLOOKUP(D1,D5:F156,2,FALSE) where D1 is where the formula outputs the plot number needed(in this case 10), D5:F156 is the look up table so 2 gives me the first column needed(In this case Z). In B216 =VLOOKUP(D1,D5:F156,3,FALSE) which gives me the second column (in this case AA).
A217=A216, copied down to A412 (my longest pair of columns is 195 rows). B217=B217, copied down to B412. C216=1, C217=C216+1, copied down to C412

I then used the results from these for an INDIRECT pair of columns which I copied downwards to the length of the longest data column.
D216=INDIRECT(A216&C216)  E216=INDIRECT(B216&C216) with both these copied down to row 412.

I then went to the TRAVEL sheet where I needed the data and used =PLOTS!D216 and =PLOTS!E216 in the location I needed and again copied down to the length of the longest data set.

It works but if anyone can tell me a more efficient way I would be grateful.